# How can i subscribe to linux commands or processes

Tags: command-line, command, clipboard

I want to build a minimal clipboard manager script using `xclip` or `xsel`.

So I want to be able to know when `xclip` is going to store the new clip, an then I can update a `clipboard_history` file for example.

I'm using Arch Linux,
BSPWM as my Window manager.

Comment: What do you mean by "subscribe" in the title?

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please [edit](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/582969/edit) your post to include information on which Linux flavor and version you are using, and which desktop environment you are targetting at with your tool.

Comment: @AdminBee i edited it.

Comment: @Kusalananda I meat, lets say a script that gets notified if a process did some action, in this example, whenever xclip stores a new clip, the script will know about it.

Comment: See how [autocutsel](https://github.com/sigmike/autocutsel) works.

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk, Thanks, i actually found other tools that do that, like this one: https://github.com/cdown/clipnotify. but i was wondering if there was a native way of doing this.

Comment: This is a *native way*. Explain what does *native way* mean to you.

Comment: A supported action from the x11 for example, a simple function that i can call directly from my bash script, that may already exist without the need for a whole 300 lines of code.